# What point in time does the Rust glob function represent?

Tags: rust, glob

The Rust [glob](https://docs.rs/glob/0.3.0/glob/) crate is fairly straight forward, as long as no files are added during execution. But what happends if the state of the filesystem changes?

Consider the following situation:

```
// The folder contains a cute giraffe and a cute zebra.
let mut animals = glob("images/cute_*.jpg");
// A cute cat is added to the folder.
let first = animals.next();
// A cute dog is added to the folder.
let second = animals.next();
```

What will first and second be? A giraffe and a zebra? A cat and a dog?

To rephrase the question in more technical terms: Does `glob` represent a snapshot of the filesystem as it was when it is called? Or perhaps when iteration begins? Or is "live" finding recently added files?

Comment: It seems easy enough to do an experiment and see it for yourself, just replace your comments with file creation code and see what happens.

Comment: Anyway, I think it is implementation dependent, as this crate simply calls the `std` functions and those probably call the OS directly. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1676607/865874).

Comment: @rodrigo An experiment is only useful if the behaviour is defined or at least not random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the source code for glob](https://docs.rs/glob/0.3.0/src/glob/lib.rs.html), you can see that:

- It doesn't really do anything until the first time you call `next`, so in your example it would see the cat.
- It reads the whole directory at once the first time it is needed, so in your example it would not see the dog.
- When your pattern matches several directories, it reads them one by one, so any files that are added to a directory before it starts processing that specific directory will be visible. Once processing of the directory has started, the list is frozen and new files will not be seen.

In your example, it would therefore return the giraffe, zebra and cat in no particular order.

Note however that this is looking at the code as it currently stands, behaviour may change if the code is modified.

Comment: "_Behaviour may change if the code is modified._" I will quote you on this ;-).

Comment: *It reads the whole directory at once the first time it is needed* => this read may not be atomic, especially for large directories, so there seems to be an inherent race-condition opportunity if a file is added while listing the directory.